# Dynamic global variable in node based on variable in route

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to do the following:

```
            var globVar={}
            globVar[usr]=["Values"];

            function1(usr){
               //calculations with globVar[usr]
            }

            function2(usr){
               //calculations with globVar[usr]
            }

            app.post('/', function(req, res) {
                var formString = req.body.filter1;
                usr= req.connection.user;
                globVar[usr].push(formString);

                function1(usr);
                function2(usr);
                res.redirect('/');
            });
```

usr=req.connection.user comes from nodeSSPI module. I need to make this globVar depending on usr so globalVar doesn't get mixed up when users runs this app concurrently. Now it works well but only for single user :)

Now when I start the app usr is not defined. Any ide how to get it's value from route on app initialization?

Thank you for your consideration on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

At app initialization, you have no idea which users will use it.

Instead, don't do

```
globalVar[usr] = ["Values"];
```

at application init; use lazy initialization instead:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var formString = req.body.filter1;
    usr = req.connection.user;
    if (!globVar[usr]) {              // This is
        globVar[usr] = ["Values"];    // the lazy
    }                                 // initialization
    globVar[usr].push(formString);

    function1(usr);
    function2(usr);
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

---

Note, though, that this means your app will slowly increase its memory consumption, since it allocates memory for a user and then never reclaims it if that user goes away. Somewhere, sometime, you're going to want to remove the user's values:

```
delete globVar[usr];
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. I went for a database instead because both functions were depending on current value of globalVar[usr]